# Average of Laplacian is Laplacian of Average

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplacian

This is something I don't understand from my partial differential equations course. Let us be in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The average of a function $u(x,t)$ on the sphere $\|x\|=r$ of center $0$ and radius $r$ is denoted $$\overline{u}(r,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi r^2} \int\int_{\|x\|=r} u(x,t) dS = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}u(x,t) \sin (\theta) d \theta d \phi.$$

My textbook uses that $\Delta \overline{u} = \overline{\Delta u}$. I don't know why this is true. Would anyone have a nice explanation for this? (It mentions that a possible hint is to use spherical polar coordinate form of the Laplacian.)

Comment: Good to have a hint, have you tried it?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, using $
\Delta = \frac{1}{r}\partial_r\left(r^2\partial_r \right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\partial_\theta\left(\sin\theta\ \partial_\theta\right) + \frac{1}{r^2\sin^2\theta}\ \partial^2_\phi.
$ Then I transformed to sperical polars, and tried to show that the angular dependencies were zero. But then I was met with the expression $\int 1/\sin (x) dx$, which I couldn't make sense of; perhaps the correct way to view this is to conclude the value is $0$, using symmetry? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Well, as you surely already know, it should be true that a (compactly-supported!?!) integral commutes with (invariant) diff ops such as Laplacian. But/and, what context? (Doing coordinates doesn't help anything at all...)